# NodeJS - Download MP3 file one at a time

Tags: node.js, xml, filesystems, rss

Im trying to make a quick node script to download MP3s from a RSS feed. At the moment I have this :

```
 const https = require('https');
 const xml2js = require('xml2js');
 const parser = new xml2js.Parser();
 const fs = require('fs');


 const URL_TO_PARSE = 'https://some-rss.feed.xml';

 const req = https.get(URL_TO_PARSE, async (res) => {
    let xml = '';
    res.on('data', (stream) => {
        xml = xml + stream;
    });
    res.on('end', () => {
        parser.parseString(xml, async (err, result) => {
            if (err) {
                console.log(err);
            } else {
                let items = result.rss.channel[0].item;
                await Promise.all(items.map(async (item) => {
                    let title = item.title[0];
                    let enclosure = item.enclosure[0];
                    let url = enclosure.$.url;
                    let filepath = `./${title}`;
                    console.log(`Downloading ${title} to ${filepath}`);
                    await download_audio_file(url, filepath);
                }));
            }
        });
    });
 });

 const download_audio_file = async (url, filepath) => {

    
    https.get(url, (res) => {
        const writeStream = fs.createWriteStream(filepath);
        res.pipe(writeStream);
        writeStream.on('finish', () => {
            writeStream.close();
            console.log('File downloaded');
            Promise.resolve();
        });

        writeStream.on('error', (err) => {
            console.log(err);
            Promise.reject(err);
        });

    })
```

But it currently tried to download each one at the same time. Is there a better way to write this to download just one at a time - and possibly also track the % progress?

Answer (score 0):

I see 2 problems with your code.

The first one is that **download_audio_file** is not returning a promise that resolves when the file is fully downloaded.

You can fix that with this refactored version:

```
const download_audio_file = async (url, filepath) => {
  const promise = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    https.get(url, (res) => {
      const writeStream = fs.createWriteStream(filepath);
      res.pipe(writeStream);
      writeStream.on("finish", () => {
        writeStream.close();
        console.log("File downloaded");
        resolve();
      });
      writeStream.on("error", (err) => {
        console.log(err);
        reject(err);
      });
    });
  });
  return promise;
};
```

Secondly, you are using `Promise.all` which awaits for all the promises **in parallel.**

You can replace that code snippet with:

```
 const req = https.get(URL_TO_PARSE, async (res) => {
    let xml = '';
    res.on('data', (stream) => {
        xml = xml + stream;
    });
    res.on('end', () => {
        parser.parseString(xml, async (err, result) => {
            if (err) {
                console.log(err);
            } else {
                let items = result.rss.channel[0].item;
                for(const item of items) {
                    let title = item.title[0];
                    let enclosure = item.enclosure[0];
                    let url = enclosure.$.url;
                    let filepath = `./${title}`;
                    console.log(`Downloading ${title} to ${filepath}`);
                    await download_audio_file(url, filepath);
                }
            }
        });
    });
 });
```

Notice how I replaced the `Promise.all` with `for(const item of items)`